# Error in webpack callback when starting a node app with reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have successfully tested my first application on localhost using `webpack-dev-server`. However, now I'm trying to deploy my application to a Digitalocean droplet, and am unable to get the server running. I can generate bundle.js file with no problems.

When trying to run my node.js server using either `pm2` or `npm` throws the following error:

```
/home/deploy/apps/web/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:30
    if(typeof callback !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid argument: callback");

Error: Invalid argument: callback
at new webpack (/home/deploy/apps/web/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:30:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/apps/web/server.js:5:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

My `webpack.config.js` file for production:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: false,
  debug: false,
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin({
          minChunkSize: 51200, // ~50kb
        }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      mangle:   true,
      minimize: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __SERVER__:      false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: false,
      __DEVTOOLS__:    false,
      'process.env':   {
        BABEL_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
       },
    }),
    new CleanPlugin('builds')
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react,plugins[]=transform-runtime'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

`server.js` file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.prod.config');

new webpack(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}).listen(8080, function onStart(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:8080/');
});
```

Since I'm new to React/node, I can't really put my finger on where things have gone wrong. Any pointers as to how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the below article to implement react on digitalocean,

http://www.davidmeents.com/how-to-simply-deploy-a-react-app-on-digital-ocean/

Comment: The link does not help with changes required for a react app from dev environment to production.

Comment: all i can suggest is that on your digitalocean server just work with the dist folder element, and keep the dist updated using your git repository so that you don't have to implement the developement mood on the server

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this is incorrect:

```
new webpack(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
})
```

A correct call looks like this:

```
webpack(config, function(err, stats) {
  ...
});
```

However, this does not do what you think it does: it looks like you're expecting it to run the Webpack dev server, but it doesn't. Instead, it will perform the equivalent of running the `webpack` command line utility; in other words, it will create your application bundle.

If you want to run the dev server, a good starting point is [this document](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html). You can probably run the dev server using the command line utility `webpack-dev-server`, but if you want to use it programmatically, it would look something like this (taken from the mentioned page):

```
var config = require("./webpack.prod.config");
config.entry.app.unshift("webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/");
var compiler = webpack(config);
var server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {...});
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I can run the dev server, what I'm looking for is to run the app in production mode.

Comment: @tekina generally, for production you use the `webpack` command line utility to bundle your code and use the result of that like a regular JS file (that is, load it with `<script src="..."></script>`)